# How to get user uid and print it outside the auth function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Please help me i want to get the user UID and save it in a global variable and use it wherever required i am using this method but its not working

'''

```
var userUID= null;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
  if(user){
      console.log("logged in");
      userUID=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      console.log(userUID);  //This statement is printing properly

    }
  else{
      console.log("Not Logged In");
  }
});


  console.log(userUID); // This statement is returning null (i want this to work)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Firebase takes some time to log in automatically. While it's waiting to log in, `onAuthStateChanged` will not be called, and `userUID` will still be null when JS proceeds on to execute `console.log(userUID)`.

Unfortunately, the real solution to this is to change your app's structure to be able to handle a null `userUID`. It's likely that it is possible for a non-logged-in user to browse this page, and therefore it probably needs to be handled anyway. There are two ways to do this:

1. Manually check if `userUID` is null, and disable features based on that;
2. Change your code to execute only *after* `onAuthStateChanged` is called, so that your code is always executed with a valid `userUID`. This can be done with Promises or callbacks as you desire.

Comment: Okay I understand the problem thank you very much can you please help me how to execute this solution I am a beginner please help